# Looping through a LinkedHashSet using indexes in Scala

Tags: scala, indexof, linkedhashset

I have a LinkedHashSet which was created from a Seq. I used a LinkedHashSet because I need to keep the order of the Seq, but also ensure uniqueness, like a Set. I need to check this LinkedHashSet against another sequence to verify that various properties within them are the same. I assumed that I could loop through using an index, `i`, but it appears not. Here is an example of what I would like to accomplish.

```
var s: Seq[Int] = { 1 to mySeq.size }
return s.forall { i => 
  myLHS.indexOf(i).something == mySeq.indexOf(i).something &&
  myLHS.indexOf(i).somethingelse == mySeq.indexOf(i).somethingelse 
}
```

So how do I access individual elements of the LHS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A LinkedHashSet is not necessary in this situation. Since I made it from a Seq, it is already ordered. I do not have to convert it to a LHS in order to also make it unique. Apparently, Seq has the `distinct` method which will remove duplicates from the sequence. From there, I can access the items via their indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the zip method on collections to create a collection of pairs (Tuples).  The specifics of this depend on your specifics.  You may want to do `mySeq.zip(myLHS)` or `myLHS.zip(mySeq)`, which will create different structures.  You probably want `mySeq.zip(myLHS)`, but I'm guessing.  Also, if the collections are very large, you may want to take a view first, e.g. `mySeq.view.zip(myLHS)` so that the pair collection is  also non-strict.

Once you have this combined collection, you can use a for-comprehension (or directly, `myZip.foreach`) to traverse it.